# Show that $\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{(k+a)(k+b)}=\frac{1}{b-a}\sum_{a<k\leq b}\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{b-a}\sum_{a<k\leq b}\frac{1}{k+N}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I am quite stuck on this problem and I don't know how to proceed. The question states:

> Let $a,b,N\in\mathbb{N}$, $b>a$, $N\geq b-a$. Show that
>   $$\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{(k+a)(k+b)}=\frac{1}{b-a}\sum_{a<k\leq b}\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{b-a}\sum_{a<k\leq b}\frac{1}{k+N}.$$

This problem was asked after having to find the poles and residues of the function
$$f(z):=\frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{(z+a)(z+b)}.$$
I've done that and the poles are at the integers. Their residues are, for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$:
$$\operatorname{Res}_k(f)=\begin{cases}
    \frac{1}{(k+a)(k+b)}&\text{if $k\notin\{-a,-b\}$},\\
    -\frac{1}{(b-a)^2}&\text{if $k\in\{-a,-b\}$}.
\end{cases}$$
Surely I have to use the Residue Formula somehow, but I have no idea how that will obtain the sums on the right-hand side. They seem to rather come from partial fraction decomposition applied to the summand on the left hand side. Doing this for $N=b-a$ gives the precise identity, but induction is pretty useless here.

Hopefully someone can give me a hint to get me on the right track. Please don't post full solutions, but rather a hint or a substep.

Thank you in advance!

P.S.: We use the book *Complex Analysis* by Serge Lang (4th edition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $\frac{1}{(k+a)(k+b)}=\frac{1}{b-a}\left(\frac{1}{k+a}-\frac{1}{k+b}\right)$,
so that your sum is $\frac{1}{b-a}\left(\frac{1}{a+1}+\dots+\frac{1}{a+N}\right)-\frac{1}{b-a}\left(\frac{1}{b+1}+\dots+\frac{1}{b+N}\right)$. 
Now all the terms $\frac{1}{j}$ for $j=b,\dots,a+N$ get simplified, because they appear in both brackets, and you get precisely your formula.

Comment: Thank you! I was really determined on using the residues, because that's the subject we're on and it seemed plausible, because the residues at the positive integers are exactly the terms of the summation. I managed to show the identity explicitly by defining $m\in\mathbb{N}_0$ such that $N=b-a+m$.